# VmWare vSphere: send automatically mail/notification on event

Tags: vmware, vsphere

I'm new on vsphere and I have an important question.
Is there a section where I can set parameters that allow a vsphere to send me notifications/email when a condition happens?
 
For example when a virtual machine cpu usage go over a value that I have set as 'alarm value' or when a virtual machine disk space usage go over a value vsphere send an email/notification that inform me.
I try to navigate over the menu but I don't find anything like this.

can I use an external app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't done it myself but according to the [documentation](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.vsphere.solutions.doc_50%2FGUID-094D4C0E-450C-4FA9-B08D-E3E806C2F28E.html):

1. In the Actions tab of the Alarm Settings dialog box, click **Add** to
   add an action.
2. In the Actions column, select **Send a notification email** from the drop-down menu.
3. In the Configuration column, enter recipient addresses. Use commas to separate multiple addresses.

If you're not familiar with alarms at all you may want to take a look at their [Alarm Example](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp#com.vmware.vsphere.solutions.doc_50/GUID-6B51A3FE-ABBC-4495-B12D-7F0949ECE7F3.html).

Comment: where is situated the Alarm Settings menù ? in vsphere i can't find it

Comment: That's explained better that I can in the [Access Alarm Settings](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp#com.vmware.vsphere.solutions.doc_50/GUID-225780B0-E974-4D4F-8078-52EDD5EDBFFC.html) step of their example.